# Get name of function in R

Tags: r, function, variables

I have a function f:

```
f=function(){}
```

and a variable

```
var=f
```

I would like to know how to get the name of the function f using var ?
I tried :

```
as.character(quote(var))
```

but I get "var" and if I try eval(var) , I get function(){}

Does anyone have a solution ? Thank

Comment: If you do `var=f` then you've made a copy of `f` and called it `var`. So of course its name is now `var`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do: `var=f` you are actually creating a new variable `var` with the same content as `f`.
In summary, you can not access the name of `f` in the example you gave since R is not keeping any history of this.

I am not sure what you want to do exactly, but the following might be helpful:

```
#definition of the function f
f=function(){}
#assignation of the reference 'f' instead of the content of f with substitute()
var=substitute(f)
#checking what is inside var
var
> f

#if you need to use f through var, you have to use eval()
eval(var)
> function(){}
```

Comment: substitute is what I was looking for. Thank

Answer (score 0):

`var=f` assignes `function(){}` to `var`. It only knows that it is a function and 'forgets' about variable name.  This code:

```
f <- function(){}
var <- f
```

has the same effect as this:

```
var <- function(){}
```