# Get name of function from loop variable

Tags: r

I need to loop through a number of functions, and plot/print the result next to the function name. I learned ([this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201827/get-name-of-function-in-r)) that I have to use `substitute` / `eval`. This works nicely if each function name per se is enclosed in `substitute()` (see (A) and (B) below). Is there a way to automatize this, e.g. by using a construction similar to `sapply`? (C) obviously fails because `substitute` encloses also the `c()` clause, but maybe there is a something that I missed to make (D) work? Or any other ideas? Or is there no way?

This is what I tried (small examples, real code has many more functions and plotting stuff).

```
# A
x <- c(1:10)
my.fun <- substitute(mean)                                 # works
print(paste(deparse(my.fun), ": ", eval(my.fun)(x), sep=""))

# B
for (my.fun in c(substitute(mean), substitute(median))) {  # works, but lots of typing for longer function lists
  print(paste(deparse(my.fun), ": ", eval(my.fun)(x), sep=""))
}

# C
for (my.fun in substitute(c(mean, median))) {              # error: invalid for() loop sequence
  print(paste(deparse(my.fun), ": ", eval(my.fun)(x), sep=""))
}

# D
for (my.fun in sapply(c(mean, median), substitute)) {      # error: '...' used in an incorrect context
  print(paste(deparse(my.fun), ": ", eval(my.fun)(x), sep=""))
}

# E                                                        # also not helpful
my.functions <- c(mean, median)
my.fun.2 <- NULL
for (i in 1:2) {
  my.fun.2 <- c(my.fun.2, substitute(my.functions[i]))
}
# my.fun.2
# [[1]]
# my.functions[i]
# [[2]]
# my.functions[i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this "one-liner"? :)

```
> x <- c(1:10)
> f <- function(...)
+     sapply(
+         sapply(
+             as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L],
+             deparse),
+         function(fn)
+             get(fn)(x))
> f(mean, median)
  mean median 
   5.5    5.5
```

In short, you can pass the functions as multiple arguments, then quickly `deparse` those before actually evaluating the functions one by one. So the above function with a few extra comments:

```
#' Evaluate multiple functions on some values
#' @param ... any number of function that will take \code{x} as the argument
#' @param x values to be passed to the functions
#' @examples
#' f(mean, median)
#' f(mean, median, sum, x = mtcars$hp)
f <- function(..., x = c(1:10)) {

    ## get provided function names
    fns <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L], deparse)

    ## run each function as an anonymous function on "x"
    sapply(fns, function(fn) get(fn)(x))

}
```

Or with `do.call` instead of this latter anonymous function:

```
f <- function(..., x = c(1:10)) {

    ## get provided function names
    fns <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L], deparse)

    ## run each function on "x"
    sapply(fns, do.call, args = list(x))

}
```

Comment: You should probably replace `get` by `match.fun` or at least `get(…, mode = 'function')`. Otherwise this will fail when a function’s name is shadowed by another variable (which is allowed in R). Alternatively, use the argument directly: you can both `substitute` function arguments *and* use them regularly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the updated answer with `do.call` does the job in such case as well

Comment: Fantastic - exactly what I was looking for! And thanks to both also for explaining different variants and for explanations. Still trying to customize to `substitute` and that sort of functions, but that helps a lot!